# why write type declarations in Haskell?

Tags: types, type-inference, haskell

I am new to Haskell and I am trying to understand why one needs to write type declarations. Since Haskell has type inference, when do I need the first line at all? GHCI seems to generate correct output with I use ':t'

The only example I found so far that seems to need a declaration is the following.

```
maximum' :: (Ord a) => [a] -> a  
maximum' = foldr1 max
```

However, if I add "-XNoMonomorphismRestriction" flag declaration is not needed again. Are there specific situations when type inference does not work and one needs to specify types?

Since I could have a bug in type declaration and no direct benefit, I'd rather not write it. Again, I have just started learning Haskell, so please correct me if I am wrong, as I want to develop good habits.

EDIT: It turns out that the [Type inference is a double-edged sword](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/writing-a-library-working-with-json-data.html#id598932) section of the [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/) book has a nice discussion of this topic.

Comment: "Nested datatypes" sometimes used for advanced data structures need explicit type sigs.

Comment: @stephen I'll add that to my list of thing to learn. Can you should a simple example?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Consider `read "5"`. How can Haskell know the type of `read "5"`? It can't, because theres no way to resolve the result of the operation, since `read` is defined as `(Read a) => String -> a`. `a` is not dependent on the string, so it must use context.

However usually context is something like `Ord` or `Num` so its impossible to determine. This is not the monomorphism restriction but rather another case that can never be handled properly.

Examples:

**Does not Work:**

```
read "0.5"
putStrLn . show . read $ "0.5"
```

**Does Work:**

```
read "0.5" :: Float
putStrLn . show . (read :: String -> Float) $ "0.5"
```

These are necessary because the default `Show` instance, if I remember correctly, is `Int`.

Comment: Interesting. I have not gotten to IO yet, but I'll keep your suggestion in mind when I get there.

Comment: @Vladimir This isn't IO. Its pure parsing.

Comment: now I am confused. What's a function using 'read "5"' this that requires a declaration?

Comment: @Vladimir edited in. In this case we have to define the type of an already defined function.

Comment: Thanks, an inline type declaration like `(read :: String -> Float)` is incredibly useful for one-liners. @VladimirBychkovsky the `read` function is classic in that it can read both `Int` and `Float` and so fails unless the context otherwise specifies it somehow.

Answer (score 30):

- when you have big Haskell programs, having type signatures often gives you better error messages from the compiler
- sometime you can derive what a function does from its name and its signature
- often a function is understandable a lot better with type signatures, e.g. if you make use of currying
- even writing programs gets easier, I often start with type signatures and most functions declared as `undefined`. It everything compiles I know that my idea seems to fit not too bad. Then I go on and replace `undefined` by real code

Comment: better error messages is a big plus, and so is readability. This makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: An extra one - sometimes it's useful to define a more restrictive type than the one that would be inferred. This can be somewhat related to your first point - by restricting the type, the compiler can determine that a function doesn't fit in a particular case and refuse to use it, instead of using it anyway and causing a more indirect and difficult to diagnose error.

Comment: @Steve314 Very interesting. I was worried about overly restrictive declarations, but it looks like it can be a good thing. Thank you!

Comment: Explicit type signatures also help you avoid the dreaded monomorphism restriction.

Answer (score 5):

**Peace of mind**. It's nice sometimes to make sure that the compiler agrees with your perception of what a function's type should be. If the inferred type doesn't unify with your given type, then the compiler will yell at you. Once you become familiar with the type system, you will find that optional type signatures can be a great boon to your coding confidence.

Comment: +1 So, in other words, declaration is sort of like a unit test: it check your type signature against what compiler infers. As a result, having more declarations is like having additional tests, which boosts confidence.

Comment: @Vladimir Bychkovsky: This is particularly useful with very general functions, where mistakes may produce a valid type you didn't want. Giving a signature means the type error will be found at the declaration, not somewhere else when you try to use the function.

Answer (score 4):

It's usually because it makes it easier to read and sometimes easier to write. In a strongly typed language such as Haskell, often you'll find yourself making functions that take some types and output another type and find yourself relying on what these types are instead of their names. After you get used to how the type system works, it can make it clearer what you intend to do and the compiler can catch you if you've done something wrong.

But this is a preference thing. If you're used to working in dynamically typed languages, you may find specifying no types to be easier than specifying them. It's just two different ways to use the strong type system that Haskell provides.

Then there are times when type inference doesn't work, such as the "read" example that another answer gave. But those are inline type definitions rather than the type definition for a function.

Comment: I am glad to hear that it is a matter of preference. It looks like type declarations are used in for automatic documentation too, so that could be a reason to write them. My main concern is that I am going to make a type declaration that's too specific and that will prevent me from reusing this code in the future.

Comment: Jonathan: Just to clarify you could define your function that uses `read` to be more restrictive than Haskell would naturally infer in order to clarify the type to Haskell that way.

Answer (score 3):

One important thing I haven't really seen covered in any answers is that you will often actually write your type definitions, and type signatures, before you write down any actual code. Once you have that "specification" complete, your implementation will be checked against it as you write it, which will make it easier to catch mistakes earlier on as the compiler checks that your types match. If you know, for example, that something should have a signature `Int -> Int -> [a] -> [a]` but, when writing it, rather than instantiating two parameters `x` and `y`, you instantiate only one parameter `x` by accident and use it twice, the compiler will catch the mistake at the point where you defined the function, as opposed to the point at which you tried to use it how you were supposed to use it.